# Asp.Net Core Share common service registrations between multiple APIs

Tags: configuration, microservices, asp.net-core-webapi

I am building an application based on microservices architecture.
For now I have 2 WebApi projects and need a way to somehow share common service registrations between them.
What I mean is... I have to re register all common services in Startup.cs for each WebApi project I add to the solution. 
Services like:

- Global Error handling middleware
- Logging configuration
- Routing settings
- appSettings.json configuration
  etc.

Is there a way i can centralize these common stuff, to make them global for all my WebApi projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For adding services with minimal repeated code, one solution could be to create a static class with an extension method in a shared ASP.NET Core project, that each of the API projects references, that looks something like:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddCommonServices(this IServiceCollection services, IConfigurationSection myOptions)
{
    services.AddService1()
            .AddLogging()
            .Configure<MyOptions>(myOptions)
            ...
    services.AddMvc();

    return services;
}
```

Then in the `Startup.cs` of each API project:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCommonServices(Configuration["MyOptions"]);
}
```

You can do a similar thing for the `Configure` method as well for using the services.

Comment: Thanks this will do